# How do I return a json object from a controller to a view in MVC4?

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to return a json object into a full view being generated from a controller. The reason being is a 3rd party jquery software that needs to parse that data and as of right now, I'm having to make a second server call to get the json data when I should in theory be able to get the data in the actionresult and pass it into the view.

To clarify, I need both the view containing the html and the json object to be returned from the actionresult without using a model.

Thanks again!

Comment: What do you mean without using a model? What do you want the final response to look like?

Comment: I'd like to be able to assign the json object to a javascript variable in the script block of the view.

Example <script type="text/javascript"> var data = @ViewBag.Data </script>

Comment: Using a ViewBag in place of a viewmodel is just like cheating.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use a view model, then you can just assign the `Data` property of the `ViewBag` in your controller action.

Alternatively, you might want to check out [NGon](https://github.com/brooklynDev/NGon) which is available via NuGet to see if it suits your needs.

Comment: That would work were the data object not a report with about 800 lines of data.  Thank you for the info.

Comment: Why are you sending this 'report' down as a JSON string? why aren't you rendering it on the server? Even if it is 800 lines of data, what difference does that make if you're always sending the entire report down to the client?